# Dropdownlist in FormView ItemUpdating event has old values

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, formview

There are two dropdownlists in a formview, one for cities and one for states. When the dropdownlist for states changes, the city dropdownlist is updated via javascript. If the city dropdownlist is never updated via javascript the values of dlCity.SelectedValue and testVar are the same. If the city dropdownlist gets updated via javascript the values of dlCity.SelectedValue and testVar are different. testVar is the correct value. I need to be able to get the SelectedValue of the dropdownlist as well as the SelectedItem.Text.

```
protected void fvEvent_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dlCity = fvEvent.FindControl("ddlVenueCity") as DropDownList;

    e.NewValues["city"] = dlCity.SelectedItem.Text;
    e.NewValues["cityID"] = dlCity.SelectedValue;

    int testVar = Int32.Parse(Request.Form[dlCity.UniqueID]);
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewupdateeventargs.aspx all the info about the event can be found here.. also shouldn't be checking `if(!IsPostBack)` instead of `if(!Page.IsValid)`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with using javascript to update the values in a webforms element. My solution was to set the value equal to the city id and city name separated by a comma. Then I just use Request.Form to get the current value of the dropdown and do a split to get the seperate city id and city name.

```
protected void fvEvent_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dlCity = fvEvent.FindControl("ddlVenueCity") as DropDownList;
    string cityValue = Request.Form[dlCity.UniqueID];
    string[] cityInfo = cityValue.Split(',');

    e.NewValues["city"] = cityInfo[1];
    e.NewValues["cityID"] = cityInfo[0];
 }
```